# Zurb Foundation's `small-text-center` is overwriting `text-left` at all breakpoints

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have an element with 2 classes on it as such:

```
<div class="text-left small-text-center">
```

This is using [Foundation's Typography Helper classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/typography-helpers.html). On small screens the text is meant to be centered, but on big screens it's meant to aligh left. However, it seems to always be centered no matter what the screen size.

[image]

Would anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. I misread the line:

> Adding a breakpoint to the front of a text alignment class will cause it to **only be applied on that size screen or larger**

Thus, to get the result I want:

```
<div class="medium-text-left text-center">
```